# Measure "dispersion" of geospatial data

Tags: spatial, geostatistics, gis

I have a dataframe of lat and longs (of postal codes of Canada), let's say they look something like this.

[image]

I'd like to come up with a measure of dispersion - basically how spread out these postal codes are.

Is there a good metric for this?

Comment: Are you looking for a single number to summarize the dispersion of all post codes in Canada? Or looking for a number for each post code that says how far it is from other post codes?

Comment: One can imagine a huge number of ways to summarize a collection of points on the sphere with a number that can be interpreted as a form of "dispersion."  Thus, a more useful way to frame your question would begin by explaining as precisely as you can what specific property of the points you wish to understand or analyze and why.  Note, too, that postal codes do not represent points: they represent delivery routes.  It would be more accurate to associate most of them with *regions.*  The lat,lon coordinates only approximate some central location in each region.